Definition of genus: cobordism or Thom space
I know two definitions of a genus:
a ring homomorphism
$$\Omega_*^{U}\rightarrow R$$
or a ring homomorphism
$$MU_*\rightarrow R$$
where $\Omega_*^{U}$ is the complex cobordism ring, and $MU_*=\bigoplus (MU)_n$ is the graded ring obtained by the universal Thom spectrum $MU$.
Are the two just the same?
I know the Thom isomorphism
$$\Omega_*^{U}\cong \pi_*(MU)$$
but is it true that $\pi_*(MU)\cong MU_*$?

Given a spectrum $K$, the graded ring $K_*$ is defined to be $\pi_*(K)$, as a convenient shorthand.
